# JQuery load content and the slide at the same time

Tags: jquery, load, slide

Below is my JS

```
$('#maindiv').load('revolutionaryCommunity.html', function() {
       alert('Load was performed.');
       $('#maindiv').slideDown('slow');
});
```

Here I am trying to load an html page and sliding it. The mainDiv initially have some content then when I call some function mainDiv will load with revolutionaryCommunity.html.

But here whole mainDiv is sliding down with loaded HTML content. I need loading and sliding at the same time, how can I do this?

Comment: You're loading the new markup into `mainDiv` then sliding `mainDiv` down. It sounds like this is working as expected so far. What else do you want to do? Your questions a bit unclear.

Comment: Be warned that an alert in a asynchronous context will almost always change the timing of the overall process. Also, what is your desired effect?

Comment: Actually I wanted to load the new content in my mainDiv with slideDown effect

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question right, you could do the following:

```
$("#maindiv").slideDown("slow", function () {
    $(this).load('revolutionaryCommunity.html', function() {
       alert('Load was performed.');
    });
});
```